# Send the elements of a div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have images of different heights, and I want to place them into a tiled gallery just like the image below is demonstrating:

[image]

However, I also want it to be repressive, so my approach to make this work was as follows:

1) Using HTML I created three divs, `#grid1`, `#grid2` and `#grid3`. And the images are placed inside these 3 grids in anther div that has class `.gridElement` which contains the images.

```
<!--Grid System-->
<div id="grid1">
    <!--Grid 1-->
    <div class="gridElement">
        <img alt="image" src="assets/images/image.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="grid2">
    <!--Grid 2-->
    <div class="gridElement">
        <img alt="image" src="assets/images/image.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="grid3">
    <!--Grid 3-->
    <div class="gridElement">
        <img alt="image" src="assets/images/image.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<!--/Grid System-->
```

2) Here is the CSS using Media Query:

```
/*Grid System*/
#grid1,#grid2,#grid3 {
   width: 33.333%;
   float: left;
}

   #grid1 {
      padding-right: 20px;
   }

   #grid2 {
      padding: 0 10px;
   }

   #grid3 {
      padding-left: 20px;
   }

   /*Gird Elements*/
   .gridElement {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      overflow: hidden;
   }

   #grid1 .gridElement:last-of-type,
   #grid2 .gridElement:last-of-type,
   #grid3 .gridElement:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 0;
   }

   #grid1 img,#grid2 img,#grid3 img {
      width: 100%;
   }
```

and

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
   /*Grid System*/
   #grid1,#grid2,#grid3 {
      width: 50%;
   }

   #grid3 {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

and

```
@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
   /*Grid System*/
   #grid1,#grid2,#grid3 {
      width: 100%;
   }

   #grid1,#grid2,#grid3 {
      padding: 0;
      display: block;
   }

   #grid1 .gridElement:last-of-type,
   #grid2 .gridElement:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
   }
```

and

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   /*Grid System*/
   .gridElement {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
   }

   #grid1 .gridElement:last-of-type,
   #grid2 .gridElement:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
   }
```

**They theory:** When the screen size is above 1024px it will show three grids by default. However when the screen size is below 1024px and above 770px using CSS `#grid3` is hidden and using JavaScript I am trying to send all of the `.girdElements` that are inside #grid3 equally to #grid1 and #grid2. When the screen size is below 770px, everying will go back to normal and all the grids will be shown.

The problem? I have managed to get everything working BUT the JavaScript - please can anyone help me to create a function that will send all the .girdElements that are inside #grid3 equally to #grid1 and #grid2 when the screen size is below 1024px and above 770px? "on load, and on resize".

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use a library like modernizr.

Comment: I don't want to use plugins, I want something very simple + I am almost there! I have spent lot of time on it, but really need some help to get it working! please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
    var toggle = true;
    $('#grid3').children('.gridElement').each(function (index) {
        if (toggle) {
            $('#grid1').append($(this));
            toggle = false;
        } else {
            $('#grid2').append($(this));
            toggle = true;
        }
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AGepR/) is a working example on JSFiddle, sorting

elements inside the grids

Comment: Mate this almost worked, but it just sent all the elements of grid3 to grid2 only and nothing to grid1. Any ideas please?

Comment: Loai! I have made changes to my answer and provided a working JSFiddle, enjoy!

Comment: Thank you! I have been trying to make it work automatically on screensize and not on a button toggle, so I tried to implement  if (width < 1024 && width > 770) {} but all my attempts failed! please can you advise?

Comment: Have a look at ( http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/). This small 0.8kb library will let you use your css media queries with Javascript. Please accept the answer if the grid stuff is working.

Comment: Please can't you update the snippet to make it only work < 1024 && width > 770? please I can't use any plugins

Comment: Mate, can you please remove the toggle and just make the function to append? I can't make it work with the toggle there

Comment: Ok Loai, I have done you a favor and updated the JSfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/AGepR/1/) - the resize code doesn't work in JSFiddle frames, but i tried in Chrome and Firefox on local machine and works fine. This should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to achieve similar effect. It uses absolute positioning instead of fixed amount of columns. Anyway, it looks the same and adapts to the screen width.

Comment: I can't use plugins mate

Answer (score 0):

This solution is better with jQuery, but there are ways to compute actual height of elements.

First, you should mark each item in grid1, grid2, grid3 as belonging to their corresponding grid, e.g. by using a class or data. Then, a kind of "chronology" value that stores the "order" for each item.

If you want all items in grid3 to be appended to grid1 and grid2, you could apply the following algorithm:

1. Get the items in grid3, sorted by the field. data value, etc. criteria you specified before.
2. For each item:

   a. Compute width of grid1 and compare it to grid of grid2.
      b. If grid2 is taller, append the item to grid1. Otherwise append it to grid2.
3. The column grid3 will be hidden.

A recommended approach is using jQuery to evaluate the .height() of grid1 and grid2, and move the elements.

To go back to a 3-col layout, just take the items with grid3 marker and put them back in grid3, ordered by the chronology value.

(damn, still messing with markdown. please if an editor can help me...)

Try this sample code (not including th fact about sorting criteria - not guaranteed to be flawless - it's just to illustrate the idea):

```
var grid1 = $("#grid1");
var grid2 = $("#grid2");
var grid3 = $("#grid3");

//compressing - distributing grid3 between grid1 and grid2
function compress()
{
    grid3.hide();
    $(".item-in-grid3").each(function(i, e){
        //never assign "width:" to any grid (1, 2, 3) in css, so it can
        //be dynamic and compute height and compare them on each iteration.
        if (grid1.height() > grid2.height())
         {
            $(this).appendTo(grid2);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).appendTo(grid1);
        }
    });
}
//return back the elements to grid3
function decompress()
{
    $(".item-in-grid3").each(function(i, e){
        $(this).appendTo(grid3);
    });
    grid3.show();
}
```

Comment: Any ideas of how we can put this into practice? can you kick me started please?